# python mysql I can't fell the newest change

Tags: python, mysql

thanks to all
I have a problem in my Python program, when I change something from mysql-client. but the Python can't feel it. If I kill the program ,restart again, the program can get the change, How can I do in my Python , so I can immiditely feel the change .thanks for your help

MySQLdb is my used

Comment: Can you show code! what tool do you use as a connector ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check update from database regularly, like putting it in a loop.